# The flow of a payment page where the status of payment can't be updated immediately after a payment -- manual payment

Tags: navigation, buttons, payment, page

The payments via some payment methods on a website are automatic -- you pay on a payment page via you bank card or PayPal and can see that a payment has been done and confirmed immediately.

For some payments methods the result or status can't be confirmed immediately. A user is supposed to pay and be notified by email. For instance, payments via BankTransfer. Or some others.

**My question is:**

how to create smooth, non-ambiguous UX page for the 2nd type of payments -- manual ones, that is?

When a user is redirected to a page where he sees the details for BankTransfer payment, what does he expect from that page in terms of buttons, navigation, text, links? Should there be only a text with Payment Details and a button "Return to home page"? Or what else?

Are there decent and good examples of such pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, user expected to be informed what is the next step in his transaction. In case of immediate payment he will receive receipt and delivery information. In case of long payment he should be informed that there is additional step exists - payment confirmation. Payment confirmation should have link to further step page with receipt and delivery terms. This is very general workflow. My answer is - user should be redirected to page with instructions how he should wait payment confirmation and what to do after this.

Comment: oh! also -- how would know at what moment I should purge customer's shopping cart? Normally I'd that after a payment has been confirmed. but in this case....

Comment: I think shopping cart should be purged after user initiated long payment - this is a kind of `commit transaction`, so this order is counted as processing. Unless you don't implement complex technology of order modification after payment started.

Comment: `after user initiated long payment -` - how would I know when it happens?

Comment: User selects payment method and you know which payment method is immediate or long. Probably system generates event - 'Long payment started' which is processed in some way.

Comment: Ok. But how do I know when a user has actually paid via a long-processing time method? maybe he'd finally decide to pay in a week from a time when placed an order.

Comment: @Serenado I think this is about payment system itself but not pages design. Your web subsystem should let user clearly understand what is going on, what to expect and what to do. Also you have alternative sources of information about user actions - i mean your banking and financial systems which generate their own events on user actions. So your page should clarify to user that you expect to receive his payment within N days, otherwise his order will be cancelled automatically, describe money back policy, etc., etc.

Comment: Again -- user has placed an order and obtained payment info. Whether or not he pays today or one week - I don't know. At best I'll see his payment in a week. At worst - never and I don't even know what's on his mind, whether or not he'll pay.

Comment: @Serenado Technically, we are Lords of Never :) Implement a kind of timeout which is acceptable to you and cancel order after timeout expires. Timeout duration is more your business question than UX. We don't know anything about your goods, terms of delivery, etc. There is a difference if you sell ice cream or from store or produce it after receiving payment. But from UX point of view there is no difference - you need to provide as much information as possible to satisfy your customer.

Comment: got it, thx.........

Answer (score 0):

The user will expect the same elements for the [checkout process](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/05/12-tips-for-designing-an-excellent-checkout-process/), except instead of showing the payment confirmation, the page should show the **payment status**. Also, it would be interesting if the user could create an account, for checking the status later. [Here](https://www.behance.net/gallery/28103125/Payments-Status-UI-design-for-finance-app) is an example of payment status.

Comment: my dear, how can it show the payment status or confirmation if the status/confirmation of a payment can't be determined in real time -- that's what my question is about! my question was also -- what buttons does a user expect on that page?

Comment: Oh sorry, my answer wasn't clear enough. The payment status could be something like "The payment is pending" or "The payment is being processed" or "The payment will be confirmed in 48 hours". About the buttons, like in the example, If the payment is pending, and it is possible to cancel it, the user should have the option in this page. About navigation, text and other options, I don't see why it would be different from the confirmation page of other payment methods.

Comment: I think you don't understand. 1) of course it's not possible to cancel it because .... it's manually processed 2) on a normal payment page there's a button "Pay now". I click it, get charged, see that it's confirmed and get redirected to a "thank you" page. What should be instead on that "Pay manually" page? There can't be such a button "pay now" because payment, for instance, can be done via WireTransfer.